# Setting a jQuery created text input to a hidden input value without overriding all other attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, input

Basically due to a **MAJOR** limitation of Codeigniter's Form_Helper library you cannot preserve the values of input elements not created with CI's form helper.

Because my form **requires** a specially formatted text input with a time format (HH:MM:SS) I had to use jQuery to create the input element. Now that leaves me with the problem that if the user enters something invalid and the validation checks fail causing the page to be reloaded they will lose the time value they entered previously.

So to make a workaround I have created hidden inputs with CI's form_helper, which thankfully preserve the time values entered.

Now all I need is my jQuery script to recover the value from the hidden input(s) and pass them to their corresponding inputs. There can be a large amount of time inputs!!

This is the HTML for my hidden element

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="timetemp0">
```

There can be **X** amount of them eg. timetemp0, timetemp1, timetemp2 etc

So all I need now is my jQuery function to copy that elements value **IF** it is set. So when the form is loaded first time there wont be any values in the hidden input obviously.

I tried this code but it seems to override the formatting done by jQuery.

```
        //creates an input field of text type formatted with a value of "00:00:00"
         var input = $("<input>", 
            {
                name: 'time'+i,
                value: '00:00:00',
                maxlength: '8',
                size: '6',
                type: 'text'
            });

            //this variable recieves the value of the hidden input element
            var temptime = document.getElementsByName('timetemp'+i);


 //if the temptime value is different indicating that a value had been entered before validation failed then make the jQuery created text inputs value equal that.
            if (temptime[0].value != input.value)
            input.value = temptime[0].value;

    ..rest of function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`input` in your example is a jQuery object, because any `$(...)` call returns a jQuery object. However, you are trying to do `input.value`. `.value` is a property of DOM elements (the underlying input box), but not of a jQuery object. To set the value of the `input`, use the appopriate jQuery function:

```
input.val(temptime[0].value);
```

However, since you are using jQuery, you could also use:

```
var temptime = $("#timetemp" + i);

if (temptime[0].val() != input.val())
```

instead of:

```
var temptime = document.getElementsByName('timetemp'+i);

if (temptime[0].value != input.value)
```